# Getting a Path value from a JFileChooser in Windows XP

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jfilechooser

As the question states, I am trying to get a Path value, using JFileChooser.  The returns from JFileChooser present me with two problems.  First, the exact nature of what I am doing involves letting the user choose a directory, then, renaming all files of a certain type, for instance, all .pdf files, within that folder while leaving all other files alone.  The problems I am having with JFileChooser in this regard are two-fold:

1)  I have figured out how to let JFileChooser show the files inside a directory, but not allow the user to choose a file specifically.  However, the return value of the string does not include the currently viewed directory inside JFileChooser when "Open" is pushed.  For instance, if a user navigates to C:\Documents and Settings\myFolder\Documents\Work and sees the contents of the Work directory, then presses "Open", the String returned as the getAbsolutePath() call is "C:\Documents and Setting\myFolder\Documents" the "Work" is never returned.  How do I get that to be presented in the final outcome?

2)  Once I have that String, how do I convert that to a Path so that I can operate on the files within it?  The "\" is Java's escape, and to use the file path as a valid Path value it needs to be escaped, i.e. "C:\Documents and Settings\myFolder" doesn't work, it has to be "C:\Documents and Settings\myFolder".  How do I get from the single slash () return String from JFileChooser to the double slash (\) Path I need?

I know that the answer is likely simple, I am just more used to dealing with Linux, where this is not a problem.  I have just landed my first job using my programming skills, and of course, everything is Windows.

And before someone suggests, yes, I know using "/" would work for relative paths, but for the application I am writing, I need to use absolute paths as these files could be on a host machine, or a network drive, so I can't use relative naming, unless I am overlooking something due to not having a whole lot of network programming experience.

I thank you all for your time in reading, if not responding to this.

Tommie Matherne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** For getting the whole path of the selected directory do this:

Here `myJfc` is an `instance of JFileChoooser` **here**

```
String path =  myJfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().toString();
```

**2.** Conver the String into a path using this:

Use **"\\" instead of "\"** in the path.

ie. `C:\\Documents and Settings\\myFolder`

Please see that you have **proper Privilege in the C: drive else your file will not be created there**, if you Do Not have the privilege to create a file in C: drive, try some other drive which you have like D:, E: etc.. You wont have any Privilege problem there.

```
File f = new File(path);
```

Comment: OK, I guess I was a bit ambiguous.  I am trying to set a variable of type Path to a variable so that I can retrieve the contents of an entire folder into an ArrayList for later work. My issue is in trying to set the Path variable with the String that is returned. The returned String contains single slashes, not the double slashes required, and simple replace doesn't work since the slash in Windows file paths are escape chars in Java. How to get those double slashes?  Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind. The cloud of stupid disappeared with the cold I had.  I got what you were saying.  Thanks again.